# CamlQuery Lookup not correct

Tags: development, 2016, lookup-column, caml-query, caml

I need to display the elements in Column "NetworkNodes" only SRV1 and SRV3 in Lookup, how to write correctly?

The remaining elements of the SRV are not needed.

Doesn't work like that:

```
Query = @"<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='NetworkNodes' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + "SRV1" + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='NetworkNodes' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + "SRV3" + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>"
```

Comment: Do you really want to query for SRV1 **and** SRV3, or do you mean to for **or**? The stated query will only give you items containing both values.

Comment: Hello Urs, only AND!

Comment: Is this multiple selection lookup field?

Comment: Hello Ganesh, no simple lookup...

Comment: Then how this condition will satisfy? In single selection you can select only one value one list item

Comment: Be it so simple I would not ask...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lookup column does not allow to select multiple values then you should try your query like:

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='NetworkNodes'/>
            <Value Type='Lookup'>SRV1</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='NetworkNodes'/>
            <Value Type='Lookup'>SRV3</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh :))